# What is the best jQuery Debug Plugin?

Tags: jquery, debugging, plugins

I'm wondering if anyone knows of a really great jQuery Debug plugin. One that will spit out friendly errors.

Ideally this would be one that I would just include along with the rest of my jQuery files and then if it encounters an error it would spit out a little div at top:0, left:0 with the error in it.

Like this:

> ERROR: You forgot to include jQuery, moran.

I realize the console is awesome and all but, to be honest, I'm sick of opening and closing it, and then puzzling my noob noodle about what it's trying to tell me.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: This sounds like a great plugin to write yourself as a way to learn jQuery. That said, the debugger is your most powerful tool **by far** when solving problems. If opening and closing it is such a hassle, just leave it open all the time.

Comment: Ha! Yeah, I was thinking that as I was typing the question in. I think the existence of the question itself shows that I'm far too lazy to take on that project.

Comment: *Debugging* error messages communicate important information. Yes, they are often technical. Learn to read them instead of trying to make them idiot-proof and you'll be much better off.

Comment: Since when is opening the console difficult? You're not using IE are you? I highly recommend [firebug for firefox](http://getfirebug.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the editorials guys. I take it none of you have an answer then eh?

Comment: What if you forget to include such a plugin ?

Answer (score 3):

Firebug is a GREAT tool. Might want to look at [jquerylint](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/jquery-lint/) as well.

Answer (score 1):

Also WebKit's [Developer Tools](http://www.webkit.org/building/tools.html) are a must in addition to Firebug. They come with Chrome and Safari, I believe.